How to config Hooks when using Webdriverio in Javascript
have a good day.
I have a error when i do my project, when i run  file testLogin.js there is no error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on browser object that is not fully initialized. However, if i run file testloginVerìycation.js, the error is appear. I have found some sources that say it is due to a config error in the Hooks in the wdio.config.js file, but I still don't understand how to reconfigure it in wdio.
this is file testloginVerìycation.js
const loginPage = require("../loginPage.js");
const loginData = require("../Test_Data/testLogin.json");
const expect = require('chai').expect


describe('API Command', function() {
    let pageUrl = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login";

    before("Refresh Page", async function(){
        await browser.url(pageUrl)
        await browser.pause(3000);
    })

    afterEach("after Text", async function() {
        await browser.refresh();
    });

    it('loginForm with incorrect', async () => {
        const loginPageInstance = new loginPage();
        const expectedLoginPageTitle = "Login Page";
        const actualLoginPagetitle = await loginPageInstance.getTitle();

        expect(actualLoginPagetitle).to.equal(expectedLoginPageTitle);
    });
});

this is file testLogin.js
const loginPage = require("../loginPage.js");
const loginData = require("../Test_Data/testLogin.json")

let pageUrl = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login"

describe('API Command', function(){

    before("Refresh Page", async function(){
        await browser.url(pageUrl)
        await browser.pause(3000);
    })

    afterEach("after Text", async function(){
        await browser.refresh()
    })

    it('loginForm with incorrect', async () => {
        const loginPageInstance = new loginPage()
        await loginPageInstance
            .inputUsername(loginData.incorrectCredentials.username)
            .then(() => loginPageInstance.inputPassword(loginData.incorrectCredentials.password))
            .then(() => loginPageInstance.clickOnLoginBtn())

        await browser.pause(5000); // This pause might not be necessary, consider using waits or assertions instead
    })

    it('loginForm with correct', async () => {
        const loginPageInstance = new loginPage()
        await loginPageInstance
            .inputUsername(loginData.correctCredentials.username)
            .then(() => loginPageInstance.inputPassword(loginData.correctCredentials.password))
            .then(() => loginPageInstance.clickOnLoginBtn())

        await browser.pause(5000); // This pause might not be necessary, consider using waits or assertions instead
    })

})

this is error:
  Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialized.
`browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.

this is my wdio.config.js
require('@babel/register')({
    rootMode: 'upward',
});

exports.config = {
    
    runner: 'local',
    
    specs: [
        './test/pageObject2/testScript/testloginVerifycation.js'
    ],
    // Patterns to exclude.
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    
    capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }],

    
    // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    //
    // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
    // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    //
    // Default request retries count
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    //
    // Test runner services
   .
    services: ['chromedriver'],

    // Framework you want to run your specs with.
   
    framework: 'mocha',
    
    //
    // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
    // specFileRetries: 1,
    //
    // Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
    // specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
    //
    // Whether or not retried spec files should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
    // specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
    //
    // Test reporter for stdout.
    // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
    // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
    reporters: ['spec','junit'],

    // Options to be passed to Mocha.
    // See the full list at http://mochajs.org/
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000,
    },
    
    //
    // =====
    // Hooks
    // =====
    // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance
    // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of
    // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got
    // resolved to continue.
    /**
     * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
     * @param {object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     */
    // onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialize specific service
     * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.
     * @param  {string} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
     * @param  {object} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be spawn in the worker
     * @param  {object} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
     * @param  {object} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration once worker is initialized
     * @param  {object} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process
     */
    // onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed just after a worker process has exited.
     * @param  {string} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
     * @param  {number} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
     * @param  {object} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
     * @param  {number} retries  number of retries used
     */
    // onWorkerEnd: function (cid, exitCode, specs, retries) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you
     * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
     * @param {object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
     * @param {string} cid worker id (e.g. 0-0)
     */
    // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
     * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run
     * @param {object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session
     */
    // before: function (capabilities, specs) {
        
    // },
    /**
     * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
     * @param {string} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     */
    // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed before the suite starts
     * @param {object} suite suite details
     */
    // beforeSuite: function (suite) {
    // },
    /**
     * Function to be executed before a test (in Mocha/Jasmine) starts.
     */
    // beforeTest: function (test, context) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed _before_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs before calling
     * beforeEach in Mocha)
     */
    // beforeHook: function (test, context, hookName) {
    // },
    /**
     * Hook that gets executed _after_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs after calling
     * afterEach in Mocha)
     */
    // afterHook: function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }, hookName) {
    // },
    /**
     * Function to be executed after a test (in Mocha/Jasmine only)
     * @param {object}  test             test object
     * @param {object}  context          scope object the test was executed with
     * @param {Error}   result.error     error object in case the test fails, otherwise `undefined`
     * @param {*}       result.result    return object of test function
     * @param {number}  result.duration  duration of test
     * @param {boolean} result.passed    true if test has passed, otherwise false
     * @param {object}  result.retries   information about spec related retries, e.g. `{ attempts: 0, limit: 0 }`
     */
    // afterTest: function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
    // },


    /**
     * Hook that gets executed after the suite has ended
     * @param {object} suite suite details
     */
    // afterSuite: function (suite) {
    // },
    /**
     * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
     * @param {string} commandName hook command name
     * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
     * @param {number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
     * @param {object} error error object if any
     */
    // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from
     * the test.
     * @param {number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
     * @param {object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
     */
    // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
    // },
    /**
     * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error
     * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
     * @param {object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
     * @param {object} config wdio configuration object
     * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
     * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
     */
    // onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
    // },
    /**
    * Gets executed when a refresh happens.
    * @param {string} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
    * @param {string} newSessionId session ID of the new session
    */
    // onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
    // }
    /**
    * Hook that gets executed before a WebdriverIO assertion happens.
    * @param {object} params information about the assertion to be executed
    */
    // beforeAssertion: function(params) {
    // }
    /**
    * Hook that gets executed after a WebdriverIO assertion happened.
    * @param {object} params information about the assertion that was executed, including its results
    */
    // afterAssertion: function(params) {
    // }
}


I want to reconfig wdio.config.js,
In my school, my project is software bug detection by automated testing.
Can you send me some more reference sources about automated testing with selenium webdriveio.
Thank you so much!
